# Array formula Google sheets returning unexpected results

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

Two sheets in the same workbook, "Task" and "Person".

I entered my formula on the Task sheet.

My formula: `=ARRAYFORMULA(LOOKUP(D2:D,Person!A2:A,Person!D2:D))`

The idea is to match the "Responsible" column data from Task sheet with  "Person ID" column data from Person sheet and populate the "Responsible Image" column on the Task sheet with the results.

The problem I am encountering is my formula return results are populating the "Responsible Image" column with unexpected data.  My formula is only returning 3 of the available data.

I attempted Vlookup instead of Lookup but received an error.  I can't figure out where I went wrong with the formula. Any idea how to write the correct formula?

Task Workbook sheet:

[image]
Person workbook sheet:

[image]

Task sheet with formula results:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(D2:D, {Person!A2:A,Person!D2:D}, 2, 0)))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thanks!